# Turning a string of numbers into an integer array

Tags: java, string, int

In my program I read in a line from a text file of a varying length...it is made completly of 1's and 0's how do I take this string and divide it into an int array? Basically if i have "011101" I want to turn that into an int array so element 0 would have the value of zero, element one would have the value of one and so on...

Comment: How can three people possibly find this "unclear what you're asking"?  Do people just select radio buttons at random when they want to close something, without reading them?  This question is perfectly clear.  And "too broad"?  Seriously?

Answer (score 6):

You could use `String#charAt()` to access each individual char of your String and then use [`Character.getNumericValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29) to convert the char to its numeric equivalent.

Example:

```
String line =  "011101";
int[] digits = new int[line.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
{
    digits[i] = Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you PakkuDon! With some small modification's I got it working for my purpose!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to transfer 011101 to [0,1,1,1,0,1], here are the steps:
1. Use toCharArray to transfer string line to char array.
2. For every char in array, use Integer.paraseInt to transfer char to int.
3. Store all int using a int array.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` works for `String` not for `char`

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. what i mean is you can transfer that char to a string before using parasInt.